# jQuery Google Translate 403 Error on translation call

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, google-translate

I'm trying to make a call to google translate, I use my google API key and I keep getting a 403 error cant seem to figure out. I think I'm using the proper script type HTML tag "application/javascript" cant seem to figure this out

This is the error in the chrome console:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=API KEY REMOVED&source=en&target=de&q=How%20are%20you 403

   send @ jquery.min.js:2
   ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
   S.<computed> @ jquery.min.js:2
   translatePage @ (index):26
   onclick @ (index):17
```

**using this code:**

```
<html>
  <body>
  <head>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
   
   <b>Text:</b> <input type="text" id="text" value="How are you"/> <br>
    <b>Target Langugage:</b> 
    <select id="target">
    <option value="de">Germany</option>
    <option value="hi">Hindi</option>
    <option value="fr">French</option>
    </select>
    
    <br>
    
    <input type="button" value="Translate"  onclick="translatePage()" />
    
    <br> <br>
    
    <b>Translated Text:</b><div id="translated"></div>   
    
    <script>
    function translatePage()
    {
        $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2",
            {
            key:"GOOGLE API KEY",
            source:"en",
            target:$("#target").val(),
            q:$("#text").val()
            },
            function(response)
            {
                $("#translated").html(response.data.translations[0].translatedText);
 
            },"json") .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            {
                alert( "error :"+errorThrown );
            });
    }
    </script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

403 error means that you have permission issues. I tried running your code and it works fine for me, I used an API key of mine with no restrictions.

Test done without API key restrictions:

[image]

I tried adding restrictions on my API key like only "allowing requests for Cloud Storage" as an example and I get your 403 error.

Test done using an API key with API restrictions. As you can see "Hindi" translation did not push through due to the applied restriction:

[image]

I suggest to double check your API key setup if there are existing Application or API restrictions and adjust them accordingly.